# how to make object public to all function in a class?

Tags: php, class

I've created a class that calls an object in the "__construct" how can i make this object available through out the class.

```
class SocialMedia { function __construct() { $object = "whatever"; } }
```

how can I access $object in the other functions (which are static) from with in the class.
I've tried to use "$this->object" but I get an error "$this when not in object context" when I try to call it from my other static functions.

Comment: I've also tried making $object public, but still can't access the object.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
self::$object = 'whatever'
```

instead and read the [PHP Manual on the `static` keyword](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

On a sidenote, [statics are death to testability](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html), so you might just was well forget what you just learned and use instance variables instead.

Comment: thanks for the link, it was a good read. i was using 'whatever' as an example. really I'm initializing a class/lib (facebook's sdk) which can only be instantiated once in a script run.

Comment: @thesocialhacker then do so in your bootstrap file and pass in the instance to any objects that need it. That's called Dependency Injection and it will make your application much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: thanks, I'll pass that on to our lead dev. See if he has any ideas on how I should handle this differently.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your object inside the scope of the class, right above the function. So, as an example:

```
class SocialMedia { public $object; function __construct() { $object = "whatever"; } }
```

Or you could try defining it as "public static" instead of just "public". As an example, this:

```
class SocialMedia { public static $object; function __construct() { $object = "whatever"; } }
```

Answer (score 2):

make it static:

```
class SocialMedia {

    protected static $object;

    function __construct() {
        self::$object = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$object` is not static then you have a problem. You need to be able to refernce a specific instance of the class. Youll need to pass the actual instance of SocialMedia to its static method or come up with some other shenanigans:

```
public static function someMethod(SocialMedia $instance, $args)
{
   // do stuff with $instance->object and $args
}

public function methodThatUsesStaticMethod($args)
{
   self::someMethod($this, $args);
}
```

If `$object` is static then you can use the scope resolution operator to access it as others have mentioned:

```
public static $object;

public static function someMethod($args)
{
   $object = self::$object;
   // do stuff with $object and $args
}
```

But then you have another issue... What happens if no instance of `SocialMedia` has been created yet and so `SocialMedia::$object` is not yet set?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your class a singleton ([OOP Patterns in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php)) but that really isn't any better solution if you want testability and/or dependency injection. No matter how you suggarcoat it you are after a global variable and sooner or later you'll find out all the troubles they bring.